# I'm trying to work on QR code scanner and I get this error: pixels, width, height = image TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Tags: python, python-3.x, video-capture, opencv

I tried the same code few weeks ago and it worked perfectly but now I'm getting this error

> pixels, width, height = image TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

[image: Screenshot of the error image]

Edit: The issue has been resolved. The code was fine, problem was my in-built webcam. When I attached a new webcam, it worked fine.

Thank you so much for your help. This was my first question in stack

Comment: Can you post the code that leads to the error?

Comment: Also just paste the error output as text in your question.  People really don't want to look at a screen shot.

Comment: I don't know the package you're using, but most likely you gave it the wrong filename, or for some reason, the contents of the filename can't be parsed as an image. You're getting None, and then an error when trying to determine its dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for your response guys. I figured it out. The issue was the laptop webcam. When I attached another webcam, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It most likely seems like your `read()` failed. You have to check if your read succeeded first and then proceed to iterate:

```
while True:
    success, image = capture.read()
    if success:
         for eachcode in decode(image):
          ...
    else:
        print('Capture failed')
```

If you still get the same error, you could as well check if `decode()` did not return `None`:

```
while True:
    success, image = capture.read()
    decoded_image = decode(image)
    if success and decoded_image is not None:
         for eachcode in decoded_image:
          ...
    else:
        print('Capture failed')
```